# Why localtime() gives different timezone on the same machine?

Tags: c, timezone, localtime

As the title said, below is the code. The timezone in the output will be changed according to the value of "tmt".

Environment:

```
[/tmp@16:01]uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-100-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 16:48:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define LOCKOUT_TIME_FORMAT     "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

int main()
{
        time_t tmt = 0;
        time_t tmt1 = 0;
        struct tm * ptm = NULL;
        char str[128] = {0};


        time(&tmt1);
        ptm = localtime(&tmt1);
        strftime(str, sizeof(str), LOCKOUT_TIME_FORMAT, ptm);
        printf("time1 is %s\n", str);

        //tmt=3600 * 24 * 30;                       //one month
        //tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 6;                   //about six month
        //tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 12;                  //about one year
        //tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 10;             //about ten years
        //tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 11;             //about 11 years
        tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 20;               //about 20 years

        ptm = localtime(&tmt);
        strftime(str, sizeof(str), LOCKOUT_TIME_FORMAT, ptm);
        printf("time is %s\n", str);

        return 0;
}
```

When tmt=3600 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 20, the output timezone of tmt and tmt1 will be the same.

```
[/tmp@15:58]./a.out 
time1 is 2017-03-23T15:58:20-0700
time is 1989-09-17T17:00:00-0700
```

When tmt is other values commented out in the code, the output timezone of tmt and tmt1 will be different!

```
[/tmp@16:01]./a.out 
time1 is 2017-03-23T16:01:07-0700
time is 1980-11-03T16:00:00-0800
```

Personally, I think the timezone should be the same since the code is run on the same machine. Why the timezone changes as the value of time?

Thanks,

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that you're getting times when Daylight Saving Time is in effect and times when it's not. Try setting to a timezone that doesn't do DST (GMT or Hawaii or Arizona) and see if it still happens.

Comment: I also considered this before. But I can't explain how DST will cause this... Since the timezone is set manually by system admin, it should has nothing to do with whether it's DST or not.

Comment: It's almost certainly a time zone issue. On my Ubuntu system, for example, `/etc/timezone` contains `America/Los_Angeles`. That refers to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`, which contains information about this time zone -- *including* DST transitions.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Can you give more details? You mean the timezone file is out of date or ?

Comment: No, I mean the timezone file appears to be accurate. You and I both appear to be in the US Pacific time zone. On 1980-11-03, Daylight Saving Time was not in effect, so the offset from UTC was 8 hours. On 2017-03-23, DST *is* in effect, so the offset from UTC is 7 hours. The offset for a given time zone *changes* depending on whether DST is currently in effect.

Comment: Read "time zone != offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 2):

**localtime()** handles summer time transitions properly.
The date you entered int *tmt* variable is one of the summer days while the current date is not a summer day.
I suggest this output format for testing ("%Z" means "The timezone name or abbreviation")
`#define LOCKOUT_TIME_FORMAT     "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\t|%Z"`

Results:

```
$ TZ="Europe/Moscow" ./test
time1 is 2017-03-24T03:01:07    |MSK
time is 1989-09-18T04:00:00     |MSD
```

MSK is Moscow "regular" time and MSD means Moscow **Summer** Time.

This is known as [**Daylight Saving Time**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).